# Equilibrium concentration from the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to calculate the equilibrium concentration for each of the materials. The value of the "Xe" concentration was supposed to reach the equilibrium, and the value of the "I" concentration will not reach equilibrium within the range of flux (1<x-axis<2e18).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

lam_I = 2.9e-5
lam_Xe = 2.1e-5
gam_I = 0.061
gam_Xe = 0.003
sig_f = 1.8e-1
sig_aXe = 2.6e6 * 1e-28

def iodine_concentration(phi):
    return (gam_I * sig_f * phi) / lam_I

def xenon_concentration(phi):
    return ((gam_I + gam_Xe) * sig_f * phi) / (lam_Xe + (sig_aXe * phi))

def find_equilibrium_flux():
    def equations(phi):
        iodine_derivative = np.gradient(iodine_concentration(phi), phi)
        xenon_derivative = np.gradient(xenon_concentration(phi), phi)
        return [iodine_derivative, xenon_derivative]

    # Range of flux values to consider
    flux_values = np.linspace(1, 2e18, 1000)

    # Find the flux where the derivatives are close to zero
    equilibrium_flux = None
    for phi in flux_values:
        derivatives = equations(phi)
        if np.isclose(derivatives, 0).all():
            equilibrium_flux = phi
            break

    if equilibrium_flux is None:
        print("Equilibrium flux not found. Adjust the range of flux values.")

    return equilibrium_flux

# Find equilibrium flux
equilibrium_flux = find_equilibrium_flux()

if equilibrium_flux is None:
    exit()

equilibrium_iodine = iodine_concentration(equilibrium_flux)
equilibrium_xenon = xenon_concentration(equilibrium_flux)

# Calculate concentrations and flux values
flux_values = np.linspace(0, 2e18, 100)
iodine_values = iodine_concentration(flux_values)
xenon_values = xenon_concentration(flux_values)

# Calculate derivatives
iodine_derivative = np.gradient(iodine_values, flux_values)
xenon_derivative = np.gradient(xenon_values, flux_values)

# Find indices where derivatives are close to zero
iodine_equilibrium_indices = np.where(np.isclose(iodine_derivative, 0))[0]
xenon_equilibrium_indices = np.where(np.isclose(xenon_derivative, 0))[0]

# Plot concentrations and equilibrium lines
plt.plot(flux_values, iodine_values, label='Iodine Concentration')
plt.plot(flux_values, xenon_values, label='Xenon Concentration')
plt.axhline(y=equilibrium_iodine, linestyle='--', color='red', label='Equilibrium Iodine')
plt.axhline(y=equilibrium_xenon, linestyle='--', color='green', label='Equilibrium Xenon')
plt.scatter(flux_values[iodine_equilibrium_indices], iodine_values[iodine_equilibrium_indices], color='red', marker='o', label='Iodine Equilibrium')
plt.scatter(flux_values[xenon_equilibrium_indices], xenon_values[xenon_equilibrium_indices], color='green', marker='o', label='Xenon Equilibrium')
plt.xlabel('Flux (phi)')
plt.ylabel('Concentration')
plt.title('Iodine and Xenon Concentration vs. Flux')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

By making the derivatives, I tried the code to see where the gradient starts becoming zero and show that point in the plot with a horizontal "y=value" line. However, it shows a horizontal line at "y=0".

Comment: Your y goes up to the order of 1e20, while the lines you are talking about are in the 1e2. They are not zero, they are very close to zero relative to the overall values of the plot.

Comment: @fdireito What I was looking for is that the line was supposed to be at y=3.7e19 for "Xe" conc. as it will reach equilibrium near x=0.25, and for "I" conc. , it'll not be shown since the gradient is not zero as it is visible from the concentration formulae; one is y=mx+c (for I) and Xe as depicted in the code.